# What android target should I develop for? Android 4.4W or android 4.4L or android 4.4 kitkat?

Tags: android, eclipse

Recently I have downloaded latest patches to eclipse and android SDK and now I'm really confused in the matter of developing my application... If I want to create a game on phones, tablets etc should I still choose the newest target like android 4.4W or should I choose Android 4.4L or maybe the earlier stable release like 4.4 kitkat?

Comment: You should choose 4.4, Android L is just a preview and you can't upload apps in the Play store with this api level. (p.s if it's a game why you need to support wear devices?)

Comment: but 4.4W or 4.4 kitkat? The 'W' version seems to be mainly for devices like watches etc and I dont want to develop on watches... Yet it's the newest target and even checked by default when creating a new project

Comment: Use 4.4 kitkat. Api level 19.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are developing a Game for Tablets and Phones, then don't think about 4.4L or 4.4W as they are for different zones of devices as per the release information rightly said by Marco Aciemo

Better you work with API 19 i.e., KitKat version 4.4.2 as it is purely for Tablets and Devices

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

Just look at the official docs -

http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

This explains with diagrams as of what to target.

```
| Version       |   Codename               |   API      |  Distribution
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 2.2            |    Froyo                 |   8        |  0.8%   
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 2.3.3 -        |
 2.3.7          | Gingerbread              |    10      |  14.9%
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 4.0.3 -        |
 4.0.4          | Ice Cream Sandwich       |    15      |  12.3%
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 4.1.x          |    Jelly Bean            |    16      |  29.0%
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 4.2.x          |                          |    17      |  19.1%
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 4.3            |                          |    18      |  10.3%
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 4.4            |    KitKat                |    19      |  13.6%
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As you see the 29.0 % distribution is for API Level 16 Jelly Bean.

Comment: I believe the poster is confused on which version of Android to target, not how to target it.

Comment: No offence, but your answer is a bit off topic. He talks about "What to target?" not "How to target and manage differences between APIs?"

Comment: yeah and still the author updates his post with irrelevent information

Comment: @Savail - Ok lets look at the updated answer from official docs.